# Ubuntu 10.0.04 Microsoft mouse "extended functions" not recognized

Tags: hardware, mouse

Related to a question still answered: 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/240176/mapping-microsoft-mobile-mouse-4000-back-thumb-button

I have a Microsoft-Explorer-Mini-Mouse (which happens to be a good product on Windows) 
[http://www.amazon.com/Microsoft-5BA-00001-Explorer-Mini-Mouse/dp/B001F7ARTQ](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001F7ARTQ),
however Ubuntu only recognizes it as a generic mouse with know thumb (back) button or tilt wheel. On Windows, you'd need to install some additional software for this mouse to enable these "extended" mouse functions. What can we do, on Linux, to make the OS interface with the device in a manner the device was designed for? If there are no solutions to get this mouse to work, can someone suggest Linux-friendly mouse with a middle tilt wheel and rear-thumb-back button?

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MouseCustomizations

Comment: If you run the command `xev` and click the extra buttons over the xev window, does it have any effect?